# Display an img inside a php echo string

Tags: php, image, echo

I am fairly new to the code world and am trying to display an image inside of an echo string.

Here is the code

```
<?php
echo String::insert(
  __("Are you owner of this listing? :claim_link"),
  array('claim_link'=>$html->link(
    __("CLAIM IT NOW"),
    array("controller"=>"listing_claims",
      "action"=>"claim",$listingData['Listing']['id']
    )
  )
))
?></div>
```

The code works fine, however, I want to replace ...  `(__("CLAIM IT NOW")` ... with an image instead of just text...something like 'img src='my-image.png'. The goal is to get a button to appear instead of text.

so far, when I make the change, I see whatever text I have typed in.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are using <img src="my-image.png"> right?

Comment: what php framework are you using firstly?

Comment: it says `$html->link` so its internal formatting of whatever framework / templating engine
can you give a reference to the class of $html object? it might have `$html->img` kinda thing [hopefully :) ]

Comment: Velox - yes I am trying to replace "Claim it now" with <img src="my-image.png">...but it is not working

Comment: Tarik, I am using PHP 5.4

Comment: @user2969767 are you using the CakePHP string class? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/string.html. If so, you would be better off tagging your question with the framework / templating engine you are using. PHP 5.4 is the version of the PHP language, not a framework.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
"CLAIM IT NOW"
```

with:

```
"<img src='yourimage.png' alt='Image'>"
```

If you are using CakePHP you should do something like:

```
$html->link($html->image('yourimage.png', ...
```